# Android logging to a file, any recommendation?

Tags: android, logging

I have been trying to investigate a common issue that is happening in my turn-based app in prod. From some reason, at some point, the turns are messed up I have not been able to figure out the reason for that. So I decided to create a log file and send this log file when this issue happen.

I don't want to use log cat as it requires permission. I need to use my own logging file so user is assured that its only my logging statement. What do you recommend I do? Just open a file and append to it my logging statements, or is there a library that I can use that would work with android for logging to a file?
Thank you

Comment: Log cat requires permissions?

Comment: To send it using ACRA, it requires Read Log permission.
I am using ACRA already to send crash report. I want to send my logs (but not Logcat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logcat doesn't require any permission. If you want create your own log, just append log into a text file.
 I tried this way myself (require write file permission):

```
public static void appendLog(String text)
{
    File logFile = new File("sdcard/log.file");
    if (!logFile.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            logFile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try
    {
        // BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true));
        buf.append(text);
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Another choice is [log4j for android](http://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/), and it also require WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: Great thank you, Do  I have to do it on the SD card? Can't  I do it as a private file locally openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);?

Comment: No, you can. It just an example that I give you.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might also want to check out the next-gen log framework in [logback-android](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android). It supports a `FileAppender` and lets you write to the SD card (like other solutions, it requires the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission for your app). You would use SLF4J as a facade, and logback in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I created the [RemoteLogger](https://github.com/sschendel/RemoteLogger) library for same situation (need to troubleshoot production only issue in my app).

Provides hooks to append, start, stop, send, and delete log file.